# Is there a widely accepted past participle for "stride"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, conjugation

Yesterday I intended to stride.
Today I strode.
Now I have...

...stridden?
...strid?
...strode?
...strided?

I'm assuming (though I could be wrong) that "stridden" is the *"technically"* correct option, but it sounds quite odd to me (presumably because it's so uncommon) when I actually try to use it in a sentence.

Is there a more commonly used alternative, that won't sound so jarring?

Comment: Where will you use this sentence? Remember that since the word is unusual, you are calling a lot of attention by using it. And that words like ruthless do not justify using ruthful. Since a stride is a giant step, you could find other ways to refer to your big lunge, prideful walk, brave forward attempt that sound less forced.

Answer (score 2):

The OED lists only **stridden** and *coll,* **strode**. I would always use "have stridden" and I see "I have strode" as dialect in the same way as "I have ate" or "I have took".

However, looking in the online corpora, among their very few instances of any form of *stride*, there are hardly any instances of *stridden* at all (figures for "stridden/strode" immediately following any form of "have"):

- NOW:      4 stridden,   44 strode
- GloWbE: 0 stridden, 15 strode
- COCA: 1 stridden, 4 strode
- COHA: 4 stridden, 19 strode
- BNC: 0 stridden, 1 strode

So my conclusion, rather to my suprise, is that *strode* appears to be much more common as the pp of *stride* than *stridden*, even in the historical corpus (COHA). This applies in both US and international corpora; and the only specifically British corpus (BNC) hasn't enough instances to be significant.

Comment: Well, colour me surprised right along with you. I would say _stridden_ too, with exactly the same feeling that you describe. Odd that a strong verb with such obvious parallels as _ride/rode/ridden_ and _strive/strove/striven_ would be so commonly reshaped to this somewhat irregular pattern.

Comment: People generally say "strode", eg "Steven strode into the room".  I've never seen "stridden".  I thought I'd seen "strided" but it seems almost as uncommon as "stridden" according to this https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strided%2Cstrode%2Cstridden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrided%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrode%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstridden%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As a Brit, _strode_ would have been my first choice.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, the question was about the past participle. _Steven strode_, certainly, but I would always say _Steven has stridden_, not _Steven has strode_.